# Catch a bootstrap error with ErrorHandler in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, custom-error-handling, angular-errorhandler

[image]
I want to catch this error in angular using ErrorHandler. I'm stuck right now as I am not able to handle this error in my customError handling in angular 4. How can I do that?

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Hey @mrkernelpanic, Sorry for the late one, I'm using "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6".